# How can I change the language after a patch?

Tags: starcraft-2

I bought the German version of Starcraft II in store, but I downloaded and installed the English client.

The update to patch 1.5 changed my language settings back to German.

How can I change my language back to English?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known bug and is addressed [here](http://eu.battle.net/support/en/blog/5571709/StarCraft_II_Language_Changed_after_Patching-01_08_2012)

The solution is posted [here](http://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/starcraft-ii-language-issues)

Basically you need to find the file Variables.txt and change the language settings back.

Here is how you do it:

**Windows Vista/7**

- Click Start.
- Click Documents and open the StarCraft II folder.
- Open variables.txt.

**Windows XP**

- Click Start.
- Click My Documents and open the StarCraft II folder.
- Open variables.txt.

**Mac OS X**

- Open Finder.
- Hold down the Option (Alt) key and select Library from the Go menu.
- Navigate to ~/Library/Application Support/Blizzard/StarCraft II.
- Open variables.txt.

Search for the following variable and change it to this (depending on your language):

```
localeidassets=enGB
localeiddata=enGB
```

Save Variables.txt and open your game.

Look in the link for other regions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but where are the language IDs, for example you put "enGB", where is the list of available IDs to change this, for example if I want this on spanish!

Comment: Please read the answer. Visit the provided link (http://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/starcraft-ii-language-issues)  to see that you can use "esES" for Spanish.

Comment: I change it to enUS (for US English) and then save the file, I then run the game and its still in russian, i check the file again and it is automatically changed to what it was before